# Finder doesn't remember settings

Tags: finder

In my "Documents" folder I want files with same extension to be one after another.
[image]

So I open view settings options and select "Sort By: Kind", then click "Use as Defaults":
[image]

When I switch the folder to "Downloads" then back to "Documents" -- my sorting is lost -- the file list is sorted by name not by kind.

Did I use correctly "Use as Defaults"? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that if I use "Sort By: Kind", it works only if column "Kind" is shown.

Looks like a bug to me, because it allows me to sort initially, but doesn't after showing this folder again.